# Android's List View. Parameterized type in AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-listview, parameterized-types

I have a `ListView` with a hypothetical `SquirrelAdapter`. Something like this:

```
public class SquirrelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Squirrel> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;

    public SquirrelAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<Squirrel> squirrels) {
        super(context, resource, squirrels);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Squirrel squirrel = getItem( position );

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null);
        TextView squirrelNicknameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.squirrelNickname);
        squirrelNicknameTextView.setText( squirrel.getCuteNickname() );

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

So in an `activity` I can do this:

```
Squirrel[] squirrels = // Lot of Squirrels

SquirrelAdapter squirrelAdapter = new SquirrelAdapter(
    getApplicationContext(),
    R.layout.squirrel_layout,
    Arrays.asList( squirrels )
);
squirrelListView.setAdapter( squirrelAdapter );
```

And so I can append an `onItemClickListener`:

```
squirrelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Bad people cast a squirrel :|
        Squirrel squirrel = (Squirrel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Log.i("WWF", "Tapped squirrel " + squirrel.getCuteNickname());
    }
});
```

It works really well. But now the really boring question:

How can I use Java's parameterized type in `AdapterView<T extends Adapter>.setOnItemClickListener`? I'm thinking something like below, but it gives errors:

```
squirrelListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView<SquirrelAdapter>.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<SquirrelAdapter> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Squirrels approved!
        Squirrel squirrel = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Log.i("WWF", "Tapped squirrel " + squirrel.getCuteNickname());
    }
});
```

> Why can't I have syntax such as "`AdapterView<ArrayAdapter<T>>.OnItemClickListener`"?
>
> Why doesn't something like this exist: `<T> getItemPosition(int position)`? Can it be implemented?

Thanks helping my squirrels not to be casted.

(More seriously I want to learn more about this Java feature...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have seen if you try `new AdapterView<SquirrelAdapter>.OnItemClickListener()` compiler would say,

> `The member type AdapterView<SquirrelAdapter>.OnItemClickListener cannot be qualified with a parameterized type, since it is static.`

What you are doing inside `listView.setOnItemClickListener` is to create an `Anonymous` class, for an `interface OnItemClickListener` inside `abstract class AdapterView`. Now, to get reference of `interface` inside an `abstract` class, you need to access only statically, such as `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, and hence the compiler error as above.

Even if you try to create a concrete class that `implements` `OnItemClickListener` you have to access statically only, such as `class MyImpl implements MyAbstract.MyInterface`

If you have noticed signature of `AdapterView` class

```
abstract class AdapterView<T extends Adapter>
```

that indicates, `AdapterView` can have `Adapter` or any subtype of it as its parameter. But to get hold of elements(data) `Adapter` is connected to, `AdapterView` uses

```
Object getItem(int position);
```

As you could see inside:

```
public Object getItemAtPosition(int position) {
    T adapter = getAdapter();
    return (adapter == null || position < 0) ? null : adapter.getItem(position);
}
```

Casting of your `Squirrel` inside `onItemClick` is needed. See if it helps!